# How to join two tables together with mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a pretty individual question. So I had a hard time finding a good answer on Stack. I'm looking to run a query that combines the information on two tables together.

So far this is what I got

```
$query = "SELECT blog_post.*, user.name, user.last_name, user.picture 
          FROM blog_post, user 
          INNER JOIN user ON blog_post.author_id = user.id 
          WHERE blog_post.author_id = ? 
          ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10";

$Statement = $this->Database->prepare($query);
$Statement->execute(array($id));
$row = $Statement->fetchAll();

print_r($row); //Returns: Array( )
```

I need to display the user information along with the blog post. I could store the information when I save the post in the database but then it wouldn't update if the user updated their information. So I am trying to retrieve the user information from the user table at the same time as I retrieve the blog post.

How would I go about doing this with one sql query? I know I could easily do it by just calling another query.

Comment: I think you want `FROM blog_post INNER JOIN user`, not `FROM blog_post, user INNER JOIN user`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `, user`. It should be written this way:

```
SELECT blog_post.*, user.name, user.last_name, user.picture 
FROM blog_post
INNER JOIN user ON blog_post.author_id = user.id 
WHERE blog_post.author_id = ? 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I'm officially an idiot. I deleted all the rows from my table. I originally had what you said, and then I wondered why nothing was being returned. It was because my table was empty. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Alex Oh no, Sorry to hear that :( :(

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, it happens to me too, I once deleted one of our customers' database :(, But, try to learn from your mistakes next times.